# choose Glibc version in centOS

Tags: matlab, centos, glibc

I want to use a newer version of glibc in centos 6,
I found that a good solution is to use this command: 
setenv LD_PRELOAD 'path to new glib/lib/libc.so.6',

However, by running this command before running matlab, it will lead to segmentation fault in matlab and avoids running matlab,
by running this command in matlab, there is no change in result and i get the same error: "Invalid MEX-file '*.mexa64': /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found.

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

> setenv LD_PRELOAD 'path to new glib/lib/libc.so.6',

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617), `LD_PRELOAD` of new libc will not work.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, I read that answer, but I didn't get that how can I force matlab to use another version of glibc to run a binary mex file, because that answer only tells how to compile with another version!